# Python ValueError: too many values to unpack in a While loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting this exception from the following code and mainly form the second line in the while loop, any hint please? Thank you.

```
def SampleLvl(self, mods, inds, M):
    calcM = 0
    total_time = 0
    p = np.arange(1, self.last_itr.computedMoments()+1)
    psums_delta = _empty_obj()
    psums_fine = _empty_obj()
    while calcM < M:
        curM = np.minimum(M-calcM, self.params.maxM)
        values, samples_time = self.fn.SampleLvl(inds=inds, M=curM)
        total_time += samples_time

        delta = np.sum(values * \
                       _expand(mods, 1, values.shape),
                       axis=1)
        A1 = np.tile(delta, (len(p),) + (1,)*len(delta.shape) )
        A2 = np.tile(values[:, 0], (len(p),) + (1,)*len(delta.shape) )
        B = _expand(p, 0, A1.shape)
        psums_delta += np.sum(A1**B, axis=1)
        psums_fine += np.sum(A2**B, axis=1)
        calcM += values.shape[0]

    return calcM, psums_delta, psums_fine, total_time
```

I got this error

, line 740, in SampleLvl
    values, samples_time = self.fn.SampleLvl(inds=inds, M=curM)
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Please post the error underneath the code

Comment: what kind of error?

Comment: Maybe because your function returns 4 values but you try to assign it to only 2 variables?

Comment: I'm amazed that, that is the only error that you are getting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a `ValueError: too many values to unpack` when you try and assign more variables into less variables.

For example, if you had a function `foo()` which returns `(a, b, c)` you could do: `a, b, c = foo()` but you would get an error if you tried to do `a, b = foo()` as the function returns more variables than you are trying to assign to.

You do this here:

```
values, samples_time = self.fn.SampleLvl(inds=inds, M=curM)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
values, samples_time = self.fn.SampleLvl(inds=inds, M=curM)
```

you assign the result of `SampleLvl` to 2 variables, but your function, `SampleLvl`, that you seem to call recursively in that line, returns a 4-tuple.
I assume that `self.fn.SampleLvl` is the same function you're in already.
If that's the case you've also omitted the `mods` param in the call.

Another remark is that a bit more context would be handy. I just assume that there's only one `SampleLvl`, so `self==self.fn`, but there may in fact be 2 different functions with the same name involved, which, without context, I find confusing.